# From the given figure, prove that $[\triangle ABC]=[\triangle CDE]$

Tags: geometry

From the given figure, prove that $\triangle ABC=\triangle CDE$ in area. 
[image]

In $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$
1. $AB=CD$
2. $BC=DE$
3.??

Comment: The triangles can not be equal (unless $\alpha=\theta=90^\circ$ of course). Did you mean they have the same area, maybe?

Comment: It is true, even if $\alpha\neq 90\neq \theta$. The pictures are badly drawn considering $\alpha+\theta=180$

Comment: @dxiv,  why?  Any strong reason?

Comment: @dxiv No, it's true. See my answer.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois The title of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The area of a triangle $ABC$ is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\angle C)$. The result follows from the fact that $\sin(180^\circ - \theta) = \sin(\theta)$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: Hey..I have a question....If $\theta+\alpha=180$ then ...$\theta=180-\alpha$...taking $\sin$ on both sides gives $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\alpha)$Using your fact...applying $\arcsin$ now gives $\theta=\alpha$ ..SO every angle is of this form is $90$? or is this due to $2\pi$ periodicity?

Comment: @user35508 No. The reason this isn't true is that $f(x) = f(y)$ doesn't imply $x=y$ for every function $f$. For instance, $-2 \not= 2$ but $(-2)^2 = 4 = 2^2$. It's the same principle with $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 2):

The given triangles can be "glued together" in the following way:

[image]

It was not a wise choice to use twice the $C$ letter, but in any case the original triangles are parts of a larger triangle split through a median, and
$$ \text{same base} + \text{same height}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \text{same area}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see with a picture; simply stick the triangles together by a side that is the same length, and see (where the two green sides are the same and the two blue sides are the same):

[image: triangles]

It is now trivial that the area is equal, since their base and height are equal.